# when calling an api using retrofit I am facing an issue like Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json

I have to get the response from the API using the retrofit post method.
I am passing the request parameter
request:

```
{
"getData":"1"
}
```

**response data from API call**

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "SK NAYAB HALIMABI G MED",
                "gender": "0",
                "age": "22",
                "mobile": "2147483647",
                "address": "H.NO;5-59-2,NAYAB BAZAR, CHINNA TURAKAPALEM,522601"
            },
            {
                "name": "MARTHAMMA  G MED",
                "gender": "0",
                "age": "25",
                "mobile": "2147483647",
                "address": "H NO 10-152  NEAR GAYATHRI DEVALAYAM STREET ."
            }
          
        ]
    }
```

My response model class for the above JSON format.

```
public class ResponseDetails {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<DataResponse> mResult;

    public List<DataResponse> getmResult() {
        return mResult;
    }

    public void setmResult(List<DataResponse> mResult) {
        this.mResult = mResult;
    }

    public static class DataResponse{
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("gender")
        @Expose
        private String gender;
        @SerializedName("age")
        @Expose
        private String age;
        @SerializedName("mobile")
        @Expose
        private String mobile;
        @SerializedName("address")
        @Expose
        private String address;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getMobile() {
            return mobile;
        }

        public void setMobile(String mobile) {
            this.mobile = mobile;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
    }
}
```

API Interface class

public interface API {

```
 @POST("abc/czxc.php/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<ResponseDetails> getDataDetails(@Field("getData") String getdata);
```

}

and my API calling main class

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().
                    addHeader("ApiKey",   "xyz")
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
    Retrofit retrofit =  builder.build();
    API apiservice=retrofit.create(API.class);
    Call<ResponseDetails> call=apiservice.getDataDetails("1");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseDetails>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseDetails> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseDetails> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                ResponseDetails serverResponse = response.body();
                if (serverResponse != null) {
                    //below is how you can get the list of result
                    List<ResponseDetails.DataResponse> resultList = response.body().getmResult();
                }

           System.out.println(  "repsonese)"+response.code());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseDetails> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG",t.toString());

        }
    });
}
```

when I am calling the API and getting the response I am getting the following error .please I am not able to understand why it is happening. I took the correct data type format but still, I am facing the issue. can anyone help me out?

Comment: The error states that you’re trying to parse the data incorrectly. It’s expecting an Object and gets an Array instead. My guess is that you need to use ‘data.whatever’ (which will give you an object) before you start parsing.

Comment: can you say how to parse I have tried many

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/04/how-to-parse-json-using-retrofit-2.html?m=1

Comment: In your interface can you try this Call<ResponseDetails<ArrayList<DataResponse>>>